# Android if statement onClick doing nothing

Tags: java, android, onclick

I have an Android test app (because I am new to Android development) that has a couple of `onClick` secrets in it that changes the screen, in particular 2 that won't work. You have to find and click the first one to gain access to the other. Before I added this system, both of the secrets worked and the changes were successfully made with no problems.

My goal is to prevent people triggering the second method before triggering the first one. When the first one is triggered, the app allows the second method to be triggered.

The relevant Java code:

```
private boolean colorChangable = false;

public void changeSecret(View v) {
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setText("Your mind has been blown!");
    btn.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    colorChangable = true;
}

public void changeColor(View v) {
    if (colorChangable){
        TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tw.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        tw.setText("Again, your mind has been blown.");
    }
}
```

And my relevant XML code:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:onClick="changeColor" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="changeSecret" />
```

What is wrong with my code and is there anything that I can improve?

> P.S. I cut some useless parts in the code, if there was something else
>   important needed to answer the question, please notify me.
>
> P.P.S. This is different from the other questions about onClick not firing because in this problem, the onClick fires WITHOUT the boolean confirmation

Comment: What does `Changable` mean?!

Comment: it's just a useless variable name, no need to worry :)

Comment: But... instead of using such a confused logic, couldn't you simply keep the second button **disabled** until you click the first one? At the end of the operations in the first click handler, you **enable** the second button and that's all. Clean. Easy. Works.

Comment: The second 'button' is a textView

Comment: And it has to be there the whole time.

Comment: ... so what? The principle is really **the same**. I didn't suggest you to make it **disappear**. Only to **disable** it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81632/discussion-between-avarage-coder-and-der-golem).

Comment: "Before I added this system, both of the secrets worked"

What system? Go back to the change that broke it and work from there...
Else I think you'll need to post more for people to work out what is going wrong.

Comment: They did the changes when clicked :)

Answer (score 0):

Second method `changeColor` **is being executed** without needing of executing first method `changeSecret`. But note the `if (colorChangable)`. This line avoids the rest of the method to be executed when `colorChangeable` variable is `false` by default:

```
private boolean colorChangable = false;
```

So will be false until first method `changeSecret` is executed...

I would recommend to add an else to see what is happening or explain what you want to achieve in each case:

```
public void changeColor(View v) {
    TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    if (colorChangable){
        tw.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        tw.setText("Again, your mind has been blown.");
    } else {
       tw.setText("You cannot change color.");
 }
```

Comment: sorry but *change the screen* does not says much to me... in the answer you can find explanation of what is happening and a possible solution, explain more what you want to achieve and I will change my answer... or simply check it and adapt to your desired behaviour... :) hope that helps

Comment: I explained what I wanted to do in the question.

Comment: again.... **I'm really sorry but I don't get what you want to do**... you wanted to know what is happening? find it in my answer....  you want to have different behaviour? **PLEASE EXPLAIN BETTER**

Comment: actually.... no... your code MUST work as you described, so problem is not here... also... not working is not a behaviour... you must put your logcat, console error, debug results or any other REAL useful information, saying *in particular 2 that won't work* is your perception, *it is working, but not behaving as you expect*....

Answer (score 0):

just add one line in your code

```
 if (colorChangable){
        TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tw.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        tw.setText("Again, your mind has been blown.");
        colorChangable=false //add this line
    }
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't make a difference, I tested it, but thank you for trying :)